# What is the proper way to use Melanoidin Malt in a recipe

Tags: malt, color, specialty-malt, decoction

I know Melanoidin Malt can be used as a substitute for decoction mashing, provides the richness expected in certain styles, and may improve red or brown color. So at what percentages does the malt achieve these results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, in order to think that melanoidin is a sub for decoction you have to believe that decoction has an impact on flavor.  My own experiments, as well as those of others, do not support that.  Melanoidin will boost the maltiness of the beer in a kind of sweet, fruity manner, as well as have an impact on flavor as you describe.  Too much of it will make a beer taste off, almost with an oxidized caramel flavor.  I would say keep its use well under 10% of your total grist.  If you you haven't used it before, start at 5% and see what you think.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Do you still have your presentation on this?

Comment: It's here http://www.ahaconference.org/wp-content/uploads/presentations/2008/DennyConn.pdf starting on pg. 25.

Comment: Not to mention the Brew Strong on decoction...

Comment: I even have comments by a professor at Weihenstephan about an experiment done there with decocted vs. non decocted hefes.  There was no clear preference for decoction and he was astounded!

Comment: Denny, what factors do you think most influence melanoidin formation? Thanks for the in info from your study, very informative.

Comment: Can anyone list some widely-available commercial examples of beers with this sweet/fruity maltiness?

Comment: The first thing to keep in mind is that melanoidins are colors, not flavors.  The way the term is usually used in the brewing world is incorrect.  Melanoidins are formed by heat.

Comment: Thanks for the input Denny. Very interesting. Your research in home brewing is freakin' amazing and we all appreciate it a great deal.

Answer (score 2):

Five percent of your grain bill is generally a good starting point for Melanoidin Malt contribution.  Be cautious using more, as Melanoidin Malt has a very powerful and distinct flavor.

I think I've also seen a comparison somewhere on the internet between decoction mashing and Melanoidin Malt, so maybe Denny will weigh in on this one...

Comment: +1 as well for the 5%. Did my first malty lager with 90/5/4/1% Pilz/Mel/Crystal/Carafa and it's a very nice, malty Amber Lager.